# How do I format lists?

Tags: support, markdown

I like to subdivide my answers into numerical points

1. Like This
2. And Like this.

But, if I get to explaining point #1

1. Like this

Only with explanation of that point

1. Even if my markup says "2" explicitly,

The number 2 is reformatted as a 1.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: You might use sub lists or bullets for your points below. Not sure though. I honestly am not sure if this is by design or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you indent all the content that follows a numbered point, the next point will number correctly.

1. Start a point.

   - Indent all following content with at least one space at the beginning of the line...

   ...including new paragraphs of any type (including blockquotes, sub-lists, etc)
2. When you get to point two, start back at the margin.
3. Live happily every after.

<sub>P.S. Hit "edit" to view the source for this post if in doubt (and for a Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy joke).</sub>

Comment: Thank you kindly!

Comment: I always knew you had the answers to life, the universe, and apparently everything!